# Django Rest Framework filter by PK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework and am trying to figure out how to properly filter by PK. I tried redefining query set, but it didn't work out. I currently have a Video class and have created several Video instances. Per Video instance I have a quiz and then quiz questions. When I go to list my quiz questions for a certain video quiz all questions that have been made for all quizzes are listed.

Example Video/1/Quiz/Questions will list its questions and all of Video/2/Quiz/Questions. I just want Video/1/Quiz/Questions to be listed. Is there a simple way to do this?

Views.py:

```
# questions
class QuizQuestionsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = QuizQuestions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizQuestionSerializer


class QuizQuestionsDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = QuizQuestions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizQuestionSerializer
```

Urls.py:

```
url(r'^video/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/quiz/questions/list',
    views.QuizQuestionsList.as_view(),
    name='quizquestions-list'),
url(r'^video/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/quiz/questions/detail$',
    views.QuizQuestionsDetail.as_view(),
    name='quizquestions-detail'),
```

Serializer.py

```
class QuizQuestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizQuestions
        fields = ('url', 'quiz_id', 'question_text', 'answer_one', 'answer_two', 'answer_three', 'answer_four',
                  'correct_answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, DRF don't allow nested routing as you want.
You will need an extension like that one cited in the docs.

[DRF Routers Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am agree with @Luiz Django Rest Framework don't allow nested routing. You need to just change your routing rules and your code is running perfectly.

Acc. to me your url.py is .....

```
url(r'^video/quiz/questions/list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)',
    views.QuizQuestionsList.as_view(),
    name='quizquestions-list'),

url(r'^video/quiz/questions/detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)',
    views.QuizQuestionsDetail.as_view(),
    name='quizquestions-detail'),
```